# How do I properly set up firebase cloud messaging for web (FCM) Using HTML, Vanilla Javascript, and Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I want to set up Firebase cloud messaging for my website. My website runs on HTML and vanilla Javascript and Nodejs for the backend. I have read the docs and still find it difficult. Also, most of the answers on stack overflow are outdated on the Firebase version.

###### This is what I do not understand:

#### Client side

- How do I get the Firebase config?
- What is firebase-messaging-sw.js and where do I put it?
- How do I get user permission?
- How do I get the FCM Token?
- How do I set up the `messaging.onMessage()` function?
- How do I receive background messages?

#### Server Side

- Where do I put the Firebase config settings?
- How do I send a message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## How to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Javascript, HTML, Node JS

### Client Side

To set up Firebase using the above tools is not as simple as I thought. So first of all we will start with the client-side setup.

These are the steps I used in getting my set-up ready.

1. Read the Firebase Docs [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#web-namespaced-api).
2. Get the Firebase CDN
3. Get the App Key (From firebase Console)
4. Get the Firebase config (From firebase Console)
5. Set up Firebase for notification
6. Set up Firebase to receive background notification

#### 1. Read the Firebase Docs [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#web-namespaced-api).

You have to read this just because I can't really cover everything.

#### 2. Get the Firebase CDN

So you will need to get the latest Firebase CDN, for me, I used v10.0.0.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/10.0.0/firebase-app-compat.min.js" integrity="sha512-QxCI6n9lTLJpOHQcpZV2klXd5DhqSrGGe1rU2Cbr9+uCTNozkfbs/w5LVrk/pIgJwd1sFaKtvWGqw3EBtguHcA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/10.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.min.js" integrity="sha512-S1ikyG/9rWv+KJjbwHJGTKeYYnmVJxcvgQOBztLUPsRY4ZoSmPK+b8jTiDrt4lSP5SlpkpEQCbhwWQJK+kx7jQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Note that the cdn ends with compat, this is because at a time Firebase chooses to switch to compat, I am not really sure why. Just go with the flow. You can get a similar CDN from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/firebase).

#### 3. Get the App Key (From firebase Console)

To set up the `getToken` function you will need an App key this key can be found in the Firebase console.

Log in or create an account [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
You will need to select your Firebase app or create one. One in the page below just click on your app.
[image: Select your firebase app or create one]

Next, you click on the setting icon and select *Project Settings*
[image: Firebase project settings button]

Then locate the *Cloud Messaging Tab*
[image: Click on cloud messaging]

Scroll down, at the bottom you will see an option to create an app key pair. Create one and copy it(save it for later)
[image]

#### 4. Get the Firebase config (From firebase Console)

Now we need the Firebase config file to set up the client. You can find it in the general tab in the project settings.
[image: Firebase SDK config]
Copy the above config and save.

Note: From Firebase v8 and later you must add all properties of the config.

#### 5. Set up Firebase for notification

Now it is time for the part you've all been waiting for. At this point, we can use the config and app key to set up the code to initialize the app and create a **Client Token**.

First, create your HTML file and add whatever markup you like. Make sure that you have added the CDN script to the HTML file.

Next, create your script tag or a javascript file that can access the Firebase CDN. In that file begin by creating a variable for the stored app key and Firebase config, then initializing Firebase and Firebase Messaging

```
const app_key = "your app key";
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "your apiKey",
    authDomain: "your authDomain",
    projectId: "your projectId",
    storageBucket: "your storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "your messagingSenderId",
    appId: "your appId",
    measurementId: "your measurementId"
};


// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const m = firebase.messaging();
```

Now at this point, you have 3 things to do, you can do it however you like but I find it reasonable to do it this way.

Make a function that handles getting the user Token and sending it to you app server

```
function sendTokenToDB(done) {
    m.getToken({
        vapidKey: app_key
    }).then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
            console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
            // Track the token -> client mapping, by sending to backend server
            // show on the UI that permission is secured
            // ... add you logic to send token to server
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        // catch error while creating client token
    });
}
```

Next, I made a function that will display the notification once received. This function also registers the **service worker**

```
function onNotification(theNotification) {
    const { title, link_url, ...options } = theNotification;
    notification_options.data.link_url = link_url;

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
       // this will register the service worker or update it. More on service worker soon
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope: './' }).then(function (registration) {
            console.log("Service Worker Registered");
            setTimeout(() => {
                // display the notificaiton
                registration.showNotification(title, { ...notification_options, ...options }).then(done => {
                    console.log("sent notificaiton to user");
                    const audio = new Audio("./util/sound/one_soft_knock.mp3"); // only works on windows chrome
                    audio.play();
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.error("Error sending notificaiton to user", err);
                });
                registration.update();
            }, 100);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
        });
    }
}
```

Note: `theNotification` is an object that looks like this

```
           {
                title: "Message Title",
                body: "Message body",
                icon: "/img/icon.png",
                link_url: "http://localhost:5001"
            }
```

Note: `notification_options` is an object that contains showNotification options. For more on `showNotification` options see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification)
This is what I used for mine

```
  const notification_options = {
        icon: "/img/icon.png",
        tag: "notification 1",
        badge: "/img/icon.png",
        image: "/img/background/sm.jpg",
        renotify: true,
        click_action: "/", // To handle notification click when notification is moved to notification tray
        data: {
            click_action: "/"
        }
    }
```

Ok now that we have made a way to send the notification, we need a way to receive the notification.
To do this we need to set up the `onMessage` function so

```
// Handle incoming messages. Called when:
// - a message is received while the app has focus
// - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
m.onMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log("Received Notification:", payload);
    const theNotification = payload.data

    if (Notification.permission === "granted") onNotification(theNotification);
});
```

With this, we can not receive notifications from our server. Now the last thing to set up in this file is the *Permission request*. Before sending a notification you must ask user for permission to send them a notification. To ask your users for permission we can use the function below

```
function registerUserFCM() {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        // Check if the browser supports notifications
    } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // Check whether notification permissions have already been granted;
        // if so, create a token for that user and send to server
        sendTokenToDB(done => {
            console.log("done", done);
            if (done) {
                onNotification({ title: "Successful", body: "Your device has been register", tag: "welcome" });
            }
        });
    } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
        // We need to ask the user for permission
        Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
            // If the user accepts, create a token and send to server
            if (permission === "granted") {
                sendTokenToDB(done => {
                    console.log("done", done);
                    if (done) {
                        onNotification({ title: "Successful", body: "Your device has been register", tag: "welcome" });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("You won't be able to receive important notifications !");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this, we are good to receive and send notifications. To register a user all you need to do is call the function `registerUserFCM` when a button is clicked or by any means you prefer.

#### 6. Set up Firebase to receive background notification(Service Worker)

The firebase-messaging-sw.js is a service worker that runs in the browser and listens for notifications thanks to the Firebase service. To use it we would have to set it up and register it as a service worker.

To set up your background message handler create a javascript file called `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in your root dir. For example if you app in on `http://localhost:5001`, the root dir will be `http://localhost:5001/firebase-messaging-sw.js` make sure the file is publically accessible and it is in the root dir.

After creating the file we import the same CDN script but using `importScript` method

Add this to the first line of your code

```
importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/10.0.0/firebase-app-compat.min.js");
importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/10.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.min.js");
```

You are not limited to using this CDN you can use any one of your choice. Like

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js");
```

this is direct from the firebase library.

After importing script we initialize Firebase again with the same Firebase Config SDK

```
// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "Your apiKey",
    authDomain: "Your authDomain",
    projectId: "Your projectId",
    storageBucket: "Your storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "Your messagingSenderId",
    appId: "Your appId",
    measurementId: "Your measurementId"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Next for the main part, handling background messaging. We do it like so

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
    console.log("Received background message", payload);
    const { title, link_url, ...options } = payload.data;
    notification_options.data.link_url = link_url;

    // Customize notification here
    self.registration.showNotification(title, { ...notification_options, ...options });
});
```

Note: `notification_options` is similar to the one mention above.

And for one very important part. Add this code after `message.onBackgroundMessage();` code somewhere at the end of the file, it will help detect when a notificaion is clicked.

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
    console.log("Click:", event);
    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({ type: "window" }).then((clientList) => {
        console.log("what is client list", clientList);
        for (const client of clientList) {
            if (client.url === "/" && "focus" in client) return client.focus();
        }
        if (clients.openWindow && Boolean(event.notification.data.link_url)) return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.link_url);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("There was an error waitUntil:", err);
    }));
});
```

Now with all this, our Client-side notification is ready .

### Server Side

For our server to be able to send notifications we need to install firebase-admin.

```
npm install firebase-admin
```

Next, get the config file for the admin SDK. The file can be gotten from the Firebase console > Project Settings > Service account

[image: Firebase Admin SDK]

You will need to copy the code snippet and generate an SDK Config file. Download the file and store it safely in your app. After storing, you can add the copied code snippet to your app and put it in the path to your SDK config(as shown in the code snippet).

Next, we can start sending messaging to our clients. (I would talk about saving the token sent from the client. That is something you should set up on your own. You just need to save the token in the user schema so you can send a notification to your users)

To send a message we use the Firebase `send` method, your setup should be similar to this

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("../your-FCM-config.json");

const FCM_PUSH = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const registrationToken = req.user.fcmToken; // get token stored in a user
const message = {
    token: registrationToken,
    "notification": {
        "title": "Greetings"
    },
    data: {
        title: "Message Title",
        body: "Message Body",
        icon: "/img/icon.png",
        link_url: "http://localhost:5001" // When a user clicks on the notification, go here
    }
};

FCM_PUSH = firebase.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    return resolve(response);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    return reject(error);
});
```

And there you have it. A fully set up notification

### My Observations and Conclusions

- While building this I realised that most older versions of Firebase use
  different patterns of the setup from the newer ones
- If something isn't functioning properly remember to clear your browser cache and Service workers
- You can debug mobile and view the console logs by using Chrome inspect [here](https://chrome://inspect/#devices). Google the usage and setup
- Android Chrome will not vibrate or play sound. This is because of the latest updates that only let you play sound or vibrate once the user interacts with your web app.
- Background notification always sends notifications twice. Unfortunately, I was not able to come up with a solution to stop the notification from sending twice. Yes, I know that when you add `notification` to the `message` argument of the `send` method the notification will send twice. But in my case, when using only the `data` option the notification still sends twice. And after making research I found out that it might be a bug from Firebase [Read here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5516). That is why I added a title for the notification object.
- I did not handle the event of deleting or re-registering(unsubscribing) a user Token
- Do not put the onNotification click event listener in the `onBackgrounMessage`
- I also did not cover push notifications to specific devices(maybe in the future)
- If you feel I missed something important or anything at all please point it out

So if you are to learn anything from this that would be
[image: Implementing push notification]